# Erro ao tentar utilizar o @SpyBean

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Eu estou criando alguns teste unitários para uma aplicação Spring Boot.

Em uma classe chamada **ComicService** existe um método chamado **getComicByApi** e eu quero criar um teste para esse método, mas esse método acessa outro método da mesma classe chamado **getHash**.

Eu preciso configurar o comportamento de getHash, por isso utilizei a anotação **@SpyBean** na classe ComicService.

O problema é que ao rodar o teste está dando erro na parte em que eu utilizo o Mockito.when().thenReturn() para configurar o comportamento de getHash.

Eu descobri que o erro está relacionado com o fato de eu utilizar o **@BeforeEach public void setUp()** para instanciar a classe anotada com @SpyBean passando os argumentos do seu construtor, mas ainda não sei como resolver.

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

**ComicService**

```
@Service
public class ComicService {
    
    private String publicKey;
    
    private String privateKey;
    
    private MarvelClient marvelClient;
    
    public ComicService(@Value("${marvel.public_key}")String publicKey, 
            @Value("${marvel.private_key}") String privateKey, MarvelClient marvelClient) {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
        this.privateKey = privateKey;
        this.marvelClient = marvelClient;
    }
    
    public MarvelAPIModelDTO getComicByApi(Integer idComicMarvel) {
        String timeStamp = String.valueOf((int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
        String hash = getHash(timeStamp);
        
        MarvelAPIModelDTO comic = marvelClient.getComic(idComicMarvel, timeStamp, timeStamp, hash);
        
        return comic;
    }
    
    public String getHash(String timeStemp) {
        String value = timeStemp+privateKey+publicKey;          
        
        MessageDigest md;
        
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        
        BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest(value.getBytes()));
    
        return hash.toString(16);
    }

}
```

**ComicServiceTest**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ComicServiceTest {
    
    @SpyBean
    ComicService comicService;
    
    @MockBean
    MarvelClient marvelClient;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.comicService = new ComicService("ae78641e8976ffdf3fd4b71254a3b9bf", "eb9fd0d8r8745cd0d554fb2c0e7896dab3bb745", marvelClient);      
    }

    @Test
    public void getComicByApiTest() {
        // Scenario
        MarvelAPIModelDTO foundMarvelAPIModelDTO = createMarvelAPIModelDTO();
        
       //Está dando erro nessa linha de baixo 
        Mockito.when(comicService.getHash(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("c6fc42667498ea8081a22f4570b42d03"); 

        Mockito.when(marvelClient.getComic(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(foundMarvelAPIModelDTO);
        
        // Execution
        MarvelAPIModelDTO marvelAPIModelDTO = comicService.getComicByApi(1);
        
        // Verification
        Assertions.assertThat(marvelAPIModelDTO.getData().getResults().get(0).getId()).isEqualTo(1);        
    }

}
```

**Erro**

```
at com.gustavo.comicreviewapi.services.ComicServiceTest.getComicByApiTest(ComicServiceTest.java:58)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(any());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de cada teste você está instanciando um novo objeto para o `comicService`, sendo assim ele deixa de ser um mock. Para o seu teste funcionar você teria que após declarar o objeto, marcá-lo como Spy.

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    this.comicService = new ComicService("ae78641e8976ffdf3fd4b71254a3b9bf", "eb9fd0d8r8745cd0d554fb2c0e7896dab3bb745", marvelClient);
    this.comicService = Mockito.spy(this.comicService)
}
```